# How to combine data from different Excel tabs into master sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below script to copy data from "Sheet1" of a multi-sheet Excel file into a master sheet of another Excel file. It's working perfectly for one sheet. Now I need to get it to run through all the sheets pasting the data into the next available row in the Master file.

Please note: all the sheets use the same password.

Please help!

Thanks,

Yohanan

```
Sub CopyRanges()
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(WB1.Path & "\Datafile.xls")

Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect ("Password1")

With WB2.Sheets("Sheet1")
  LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
WB2.Sheets("71235").Range("B6:M" & LastRow).Copy
WB1.Sheets("Output").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet1").Protect ("FTCCTOR")
WB2.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyRanges()
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(WB1.Path & "\Datafile.xls")

For Each sht In WB2.Sheets
    With sht
        .Unprotect ("Password1")
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        WB1.Sheets("Output").Range("A" & WB1.Sheets("Output").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Resize(LastRow - 5, 12).value = .Range("B6:M" & LastRow).value
        .Protect ("Password1")
    End With
Next sht
WB2.Close
End Sub
```

When only wanting the values it is faster to assign the values than to copy them.